Python Turtle Module, inheriting from Screen-class, function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
I am currently programming a Pong game in Python. For this, I am using the Python Turtle module. In the Pong game, the main idea is that there are two paddles (one on the left, one on the right) that hit a ball back and forth between them. This is the current state, which is running without any issues:
main.py: 

from day22.game_screen import GameScreen
from day22.paddle import Paddle

game_screen = GameScreen()
screen = game_screen.get_screen()

right_paddle = Paddle((350, 0))
left_paddle = Paddle((-350, 0))

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(key="Up", fun=right_paddle.go_up)
screen.onkey(key="Down", fun=right_paddle.go_down)
screen.onkey(key="w", fun=left_paddle.go_up)
screen.onkey(key="s", fun=left_paddle.go_down)

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()

paddle.py:
# some code to handle the initialization of the paddles...

game_screen.py:

from turtle import Screen

class GameScreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.screen.bgcolor("black")
        self.screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
        self.screen.title("Pong")
        self.screen.tracer(0)

    def get_screen(self):
        return self.screen

I wanted to refactor the code so that the GameScreen class inherits from the Screen class of the Turtle module. This would also make the get_screen() method redundant. So, I did the following refactoring:
game_screen.py:

from turtle import Screen

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bgcolor("black")
        self.setup(width=800, height=600)
        self.title("Pong")
        self.tracer(0)

main.py:

from day22.game_screen import GameScreen
from day22.paddle import Paddle

game_screen = GameScreen()

right_paddle = Paddle((350, 0))
left_paddle = Paddle((-350, 0))

game_screen.listen()
game_screen.onkey(key="Up", fun=right_paddle.go_up)
game_screen.onkey(key="Down", fun=right_paddle.go_down)
game_screen.onkey(key="w", fun=left_paddle.go_up)
game_screen.onkey(key="s", fun=left_paddle.go_down)

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    game_screen.update()

game_screen.exitonclick()

When I run this code now, I get the following error: TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str. Is the reason for the error that the Screen class in the Turtle module is marked as a singleton and therefore cannot be inherited from, or am I making another mistake?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

which part of code makes problem? don't expect that we will run all code to see it in full error message. Besides we can't run it because we don't have code for Paddle.

it seems Screen is not class, but function - so you can't use function to create new class. This function returns value of Turtle._screen which is instance of class _Screen(TurtleScreen) - so you may try to use _Screen to create own class. BTW: Using import tutrle print( turtle.__file__ ) you can get full path to source code.

Two design suggestions: (1) Don't inherit from third party libraries, especially in turtle; use composition instead, like you're doing in the first GameScreen. (2) Use ontimer rather than while.

Using this code you can get path to source code
import turtle
print( turtle.__file__ )

And in source code you can see that Screen is not class but function
def Screen():
    """Return the singleton screen object.
    If none exists at the moment, create a new one and return it,
    else return the existing one."""
    if Turtle._screen is None:
        Turtle._screen = _Screen()
    return Turtle._screen

and you can't use function to create class
You may try to use class turtle._Screen (not instances Turtle._screen)
import turtle

class GameScreen(turtle._Screen):

But I don't know if it will work all time because it can have some mess in code - probably nobody expect that someone will try to create own class.

To work without error message I had to assign class to Turtle._screen
(like in function Screen())
class GameScreen(turtle._Screen):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        turtle.Turtle._screen = self


Full working code with other changes
I use onkeypress and onkeyrelease to set True/False on variables move_up and move_down, and function move() uses it to move turtle. And I run move() in while game_is_on.
This way it works better on my computer - because it doesn't have to wait for repeating (pressed) keys by system.
import time
import turtle
#print( turtle.__file__ )

# --- classes ---

class GameScreen(turtle._Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        turtle.Turtle._screen = self
        self.bgcolor("black")
        self.setup(width=800, height=600)
        self.title("Pong")
        self.tracer(0)
       
class Paddle(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, screen, pos, key1, key2, color='white'):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        
        self.shape('square')
        self.penup()
        self.left(90)
        self.goto(pos)
        self.color(color)

        self.move_up   = False
        self.move_down = False
        
        self.screen.onkeypress(  key=key1, fun=lambda:self.set_move_up(True))
        self.screen.onkeyrelease(key=key1, fun=lambda:self.set_move_up(False))

        self.screen.onkeypress(  key=key2, fun=lambda:self.set_move_down(True))
        self.screen.onkeyrelease(key=key2, fun=lambda:self.set_move_down(False))
        
    def set_move_up(self, value):
        print('[DEBUG] set move up:', value)    
        self.move_up = value

    def set_move_down(self, value):
        print('[DEBUG] set move down:', value)    
        self.move_down = value
                
    def move(self):
        print('[DEBUG] move:', self.move_up, self.move_down)
        if self.move_up and self.ycor() < 250:
            print('[DEBUG] go up')
            self.forward(10)
        if self.move_down and self.ycor() > -250:
            print('[DEBUG] go down')
            self.backward(10)

# --- functions ---

def exit_game():
    global game_is_on

    print('[DEBUG] exit game')
    game_is_on = False
    
# --- main code ---

game_screen = GameScreen()

right_paddle = Paddle(game_screen, ( 350, 0), 'Up', 'Down', 'red')
left_paddle  = Paddle(game_screen, (-350, 0), 'w' ,'s', 'green')

game_screen.listen()

game_screen.onkey(key="Escape", fun=exit_game) 

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    right_paddle.move()
    left_paddle.move()
    game_screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)   # use less CPU, and run with the same speed on different computers

#print('Click screen to exit')
turtle.color("white")
turtle.write('Click screen to exit', True, align="center", font=('Arial', 20, 'normal'))
game_screen.exitonclick()


_Screen is not part of the public API. Inheriting from screen is an antipattern--it wasn't designed for that. Use composition instead. Also, please see this regarding EDIT:.

@ggorlen OP already use composition in original code - and OP asked how to use inheritiation :) . Turtle doesn't have public class for Screen so it hard to do inheritiation in correct way :/ But if you have some idea how do it better then maybe show it as another answer. OP will have opportunity to compare them.

That's right--it's an XY problem. They already have the way to hammer a nail but they're asking how to do it with a screwdriver. The correct answer is "use composition, Turtle does not support a public API for Screen inheritance". Sure, you can hack a solution by using private variables, but just because you can doesn't mean you should. Turtle is often taught to beginners, and inheritance is still trendy in education, so educators try hard to work it into turtle assignments even though it doesn't belong.

@ggorlen Turtle is nice for drawing with recursion - and it seems good for showing how works recursion (and how to use functions), but I see on Stackoveflow how people try to use it for more complex programs which sometimes need to access tkinter :/  And this makes problems.
